# Cron job ignores part of trigger url

Tags: linux, cron, shell

I created a cron job to trigger a url at set times, which in turn starts a product import script. But for some reason part of the trigger url with parameters is stripped away.

I set the cron job like this:

```
/usr/bin/wget -O /dev/null http://domain.nl/wp-cron.php?import_key=XXXXXXXXXX&import_id=3&action=processing
```

But it only runs `http://domain.nl/wp-cron.php?import_key=XXXXXXXXXX`.  Where is the last part that actually tells the script what to do?

Who knows why it behaves like this and how to get it to work?

Comment: put the url in single quotes.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[The ampersand character (`&`) actually means something in Linux (well, in a Bourne-compatible shell).  It means: run the command as a background task](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/86247/29235).

Because of that, you are actually telling cron to run `/usr/bin/wget -O /dev/null http://domain.nl/wp-cron.php?import_key=XXXXXXXXXX` in the background, and then to do `action=processing`.  And that's what cron is doing for you - what you told it to do.

To get around this, you need to escape the `&` character, so that it gets processed as part of the url, rather than being interpreted as a control character.

The easiest solution is to encapsulate the url in quotes.

Comment: What about a space in a query parameter? For example, `date=2021-10-07 03:00:00`, does it work if I wrap entire url in quotes?

Answer (score 3):

In addition to the ampersand that was already mentioned, you also have to be careful with a `%` character in a cron entry. `%` in a cron entry will be interpreted as a line break and has to be escaped with a backslash(`\%`). Make sure the `import_key` that you censored doesn't have such a character. Also, URLs often have `%` in them to escape certain characters like space (), `=`, etc.